# GPU seemingly randomly returns NaN

Tags: cuda, gpu, differential-equations

I have been stumped on this for a while and was hoping someone could shed some light on this problem.

When running a kernal on a GTX690, occasionally it will return NaN as one of the values and ruin the rest of the simulation.  Also, the NaN values show up seemingly randomly at different locations and different times each time I run the simulation. This problem also occurs on a Geforce 630M chip, so I don't think the card is the problem.

When I rewrote the kernal to work in double precision, it seemed to make the problem occur less often, but didn't quite solve it.  My guess is there is something going on during the kernal execution that I am unaware of, causing this problem.  My code is below.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


__global__ void getvstate (float *States,  float *Vstate, int *mySimsize) {
int Simsize = mySimsize[0];
int idx= Simsize*blockIdx.x +threadIdx.x;
Vstate[idx] = States[13*idx];
}


__global__ void Evaluate_Functions (float *States,  int *mySimsize) {

int Simsize = mySimsize[0];
int idx= Simsize*blockIdx.x +threadIdx.x;

double conn = 2;
double dx = 1.0;
double dy = dx;
double dt = .1;




double V = (double)States[idx*13 + 0];
double Cai = (double)States[idx*13 + 1];
double Casr = (double)States[idx*13 + 2];
double f = (double)States[idx*13 + 3];
double d = (double)States[idx*13 + 4];
double m = (double)States[idx*13 + 5];
double h = (double)States[idx*13 + 6];
double j = (double)States[idx*13 + 7];
double fca = (double)States[idx*13 + 8];
double Xkr = (double)States[idx*13 + 9];
double Xks = (double)States[idx*13 + 10];
double Xto = (double)States[idx*13 + 11];
double Yto = (double)States[idx*13 + 12];


////Constants///////////
double Gna = 12.8;
double Gk1 = 2.8;
double Gkr = 0.0136;
double Gks = 0.0245;
double Gkp = 0.002216;
double Gto = 0.23815;
double Gnab = 0.0031;
double Gcab = 0.0003842;
double Pca = 0.0000226;
double Pcak = 5.97e-7;
double Prel = 6;
double Pleak = 0.000001;
double Ibarnak = 0.693;
double Icahalf = -0.265;
double Ibarpca = 0.05;
double R = 8.314;
double T = 310;
double F = 96.5;
double Acap = 1.534e-4;
double Csc = 1;
double nu = .35;
double ksat = 0.2;
double knaca = 1500;
double Kmfca = 0.18;
double Kmk1 = 13;
double Kmna = 87.5;
double Kmca = 1380;
double Kmnai= 10;
double Kmko = 1.5;
double Kmpca = 0.05;
double Kmup = 0.32;
double CMDN = 10;
double CSQN = 10000;
double Kcmdn = 2;
double Kcsqn = 600;
double Vup = 0.1;
double Vmyo = 2.584e-5;
double Vsr = 2e-6;
double Nai = 10;
double Ki = 149.4;
double Nao = 138;
double Ko = 4;
double Cao = 2000;

//sigmoids
double alpha_m = .32*(V+47.13)/(1-exp(-.1*(V+47.13)));
double beta_m = 0.08*exp(-V/11);
double alpha_h = 0.135*exp((V+80)/(-6.8));
double beta_h = 7.5/(1+exp(-.1*(V+11)));
double alpha_j = (0.175*exp((V+100)/(-23)))/(1+exp(.15*(V+79)));
double beta_j = 0.3/(1+exp(-.1*(V+32)));

double Ena = (R*T/F)*log(Nao/Nai);
double Ina = Gna*m*m*m*h*j*(V-Ena);

double Ek = (R*T/F)*log(Ko/Ki);
double Kinf = 1/(2+exp(1.62*(F/(R*T))*(V-Ek)));
double Ikl = Gk1*Kinf*(Ko/(Ko+Kmk1))*(V-Ek);

double Rv = 1/(1+2.5*exp(.1*(V+28)));
double taukr = 43 + 1/(exp(-5.495 + .1691*V) + exp(-7.677-0.0128*V));
double Xkrinf = 1/(1+exp(-2.182-0.1819*V));
double Ikr = Gkr*Rv*Xkr*sqrt(Ko/4)*(V-Ek);

double tauks = 1/((.0000719*(V-10)/(1-exp(-.148*(V-10)))) + (.000131*(V-10)/(exp(.0687*(V-10))-1)));
double Xksinf = 1/(1+exp((V-16)/(-13.6)));
double Eks = (R*T/F)*log((Ko + 0.01833*Nao)/(Ki + 0.01833*Nai));
double Iks = Gks*Xks*Xks*(V-Eks);

double alpha_xto = 0.04516*exp(0.03577*V);
double beta_xto = 0.0989*exp(-0.06237*V);
double alpha_yto = (0.005415*exp((V+33.5)/(-5)))/(1+0.051335*exp((V+33.5)/(-5)));
double beta_yto =  (0.005415*exp((V+33.5)/(5)))/(1+0.051335*exp((V+33.5)/(5)));
double Ito = Gto*Xto*Yto*(V-Ek);

double Kkp = 1/(1+exp((7.488-V)/(5.98)));
double Ikp = Gkp*Kkp*(V-Ek);

double sigma = (1/7)*(exp(Nao/67.3)-1);
double fnak = 1/(1+.1245*exp(-.1*(V*F)/(R*T)) + 0.0365*sigma*exp(-V*F/(R*T)));
double Inak = Ibarnak*fnak*(1/(1+   sqrt((Kmnai/Nai)*(Kmnai/Nai)*(Kmnai/Nai))   ))*(Ko/(Ko+Kmko));

double Eca = ((R*T)/(2*F))*log(Cao/Cai);
double Icab = Gcab*(V-Eca);
double Ipca = (Ibarpca*Cai)/(Kmpca+Cai);
double Inaca = (knaca/(   Kmna*Kmna*Kmna    +   Nao*Nao*Nao   )) * (1/(Kmca + Cao)) * (1/(1+ksat*exp(V*F*(nu-1)/(R*T)))) * (exp(V*F*nu/(R*T))*Nai*Nai*Nai*Cao-exp(V*F*(nu-1)/(R*T))*Nao*Nao*Nao*Cai);
double Inab = Gnab*(V-Ena);

double finf = 1/(1+exp((V+12.5)/5));
double tauf = 30 + 200/(1 + exp((V+20)/9.5));
double dinf = 1/(1+exp((V+10)/-6.24));
double taud = 1 / (   (.25*exp(-.01*V))/(1 + exp(-.07*V)) + (0.07*exp(-0.05*(V+40)))/(1+exp(.05*(V+40))));
double fcainf = 1/(1 + (Cai/Kmfca)*(Cai/Kmfca)*(Cai/Kmfca)   );
double taufca = 30;

double Ibarca = (Pca/Csc)*(4*V*F*F/(R*T))*(-.341*Cao+Cai*exp(2*V*F/(R*T)))/(exp(2*V*F/(R*T))-1);
double Ica = Ibarca*f*d*fca;

double Icak = (Pcak/Csc)*(f*d*fca/(1+(Ibarca/Icahalf)))*(1000*V*F*F/(R*T))*(Ki*exp(V*F/(R*T))-Ko)/(exp(V*F/(R*T))-1);

double Betasr = 1/(1 + ((CSQN*Kcsqn)/(   (Kcsqn+Casr)* (Kcsqn+Casr)   )));
double Jleak = Pleak*(Casr - Cai);
double Jup = Vup/(1 +   (Kmup/Cai)*(Kmup/Cai)    );
double gamma = 1/(1 + (2000/Casr)* (2000/Casr)*(2000/Casr)    );
double Jrel = Prel*f*d*fca*(gamma*Casr-Cai)/(1 + 1.65*exp(V/20));
double Betai = 1/(1 + (CMDN*Kcmdn)/(    (Kcmdn+Cai)*(Kcmdn+Cai)    ));

double currents = -(Ina + Ikl + Ikr + Iks + Ito + Ikp + Inak + Inaca + Inab + Icab + Ipca + Ica + Icak);

int yy = blockIdx.x;
int xx = threadIdx.x;
int Vplusidx   = 13*(Simsize*min(yy+1,Simsize-1) +threadIdx.x);
int Vminusidx  = 13*(Simsize*max(0,yy-1) + threadIdx.x);
int Vrightidx = 13*(Simsize*blockIdx.x + min(Simsize-1,xx + 1));
int Vleftidx = 13*(Simsize*blockIdx.x + max(0,xx-1));

__syncthreads();
//Update states

float Vbuf;

////////////////////RHS Function Evaluation
Vbuf = (float)((1-(4*dt*conn)/(2*dx*dx))*V + (dt*conn)/(2*dx*dx)*(States[Vplusidx]+States[Vminusidx]+States[Vleftidx] + States[Vrightidx]) + dt*currents/2);
//////////////////////


States[13*idx + 1] = (float)(.5*dt*Betai*(Jrel + Jleak - Jup - ((Acap*Csc)/(2*F*Vmyo))*(Ica+Icab+Ipca-2*Inaca)) + Cai);
States[13*idx + 2] = (float)(.5*dt*Betasr*(Jup-Jleak-Jrel)*(Vmyo/Vsr) + Casr);
States[13*idx + 3] =  (float)((f-finf)*exp(-(.5*dt)/tauf) + finf);
States[13*idx + 4] =  (float)((d-dinf)*exp(-(.5*dt)/taud) + dinf);

double y6inf = alpha_m/(alpha_m + beta_m);
States[13*idx + 5] = (float)(y6inf-(y6inf-m)*exp(-(.5*dt)*(alpha_m+beta_m)));

double y7inf = alpha_h/(alpha_h + beta_h);
States[13*idx + 6] = (float)(y7inf-(y7inf-h)*exp(-(.5*dt)*(alpha_h+beta_h)));

double y8inf = alpha_j/(alpha_j + beta_j);
States[13*idx + 7] = (float)(y8inf-(y8inf-j)*exp(-(.5*dt)*(alpha_j+beta_j)));

States[13*idx + 8] = (float)((fca-fcainf)*exp(-(.5*dt)/taufca) + fcainf);
States[13*idx + 9] = (float)((Xkr-Xkrinf)*exp(-(.5*dt)/taukr) + Xkrinf);
States[13*idx + 10] = (float)((Xks-Xksinf)*exp(-(.5*dt)/tauks) + Xksinf);

double y12inf = alpha_xto/(alpha_xto + beta_xto);
States[13*idx + 11] = (float)(y12inf-(y12inf-Xto)*exp(-(.5*dt)*(alpha_xto+beta_xto)));

double y13inf = alpha_yto/(alpha_yto + beta_yto);
States[13*idx + 12] = (float)(y13inf-(y13inf-Yto)*exp(-(.5*dt)*(alpha_yto+beta_yto)));
__syncthreads();
States[13*idx] = Vbuf;

}


void main(){


int myco = 0;
int const steptot =20000;
clock_t t1,t2;
t1=clock();
int mycount = 0;
int count2 = 0;
cudaSetDevice(1);
FILE * States = fopen("C:\\Users\\ddwilson\\Desktop\\Isostable_Improvement\\foxstates.dat", "wb");

const int gridsize = 256;


float *h_states = new float[13*gridsize*gridsize];
float *h_Vstates = new float[gridsize*gridsize];

FILE * myinits = fopen("myinits.bin","rb");
float h_myinits[13];
fread(h_myinits,sizeof(float),13,myinits);

for(int i = 0;i<gridsize/2;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<gridsize/2;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k<13;k++){
        h_states[13*(j+gridsize*i) + k] = h_myinits[k];
        }
    }
}

fread(h_myinits,sizeof(float),13,myinits);
for(int i = gridsize/2;i<gridsize;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<gridsize/2;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k<13;k++){
        h_states[13*(j+gridsize*i) + k] = h_myinits[k];
        }
    }
}


fread(h_myinits,sizeof(float),13,myinits);
for(int i = gridsize/2;i<gridsize;i++){
    for(int j = gridsize/2; j<gridsize;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k<13;k++){
        h_states[13*(j+gridsize*i) + k] = h_myinits[k];
        }
    }
}

fread(h_myinits,sizeof(float),13,myinits);
//h_myinits[0] = 10;
for(int i = 0;i<gridsize/2;i++){
    for(int j = gridsize/2; j<gridsize;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k<13;k++){
        h_states[13*(j+gridsize*i) + k] = h_myinits[k];
        }
    }
}


float *d_ucontrol;
float *d_states;
float *d_Vstates;
int *d_Simsize;
int cudagrid[1];
cudagrid[0] = gridsize;


cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_states, 13*gridsize*gridsize*sizeof(float) );
cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_Vstates, gridsize*gridsize*sizeof(float) );
cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_Simsize,sizeof(const int) );

cudaMemcpy(d_states,h_states,13*gridsize*gridsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_Simsize,cudagrid,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);




for(int m = 0;m<steptot;m++){

//Evaluate_Functions<<<gridsize,gridsize>>>(d_states,d_Simsize);
Evaluate_Functions<<<gridsize,gridsize>>>(d_states,d_Simsize);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

/*if (m==9500){
FILE * statetemp = fopen("initstate.bin","wb");
fwrite(h_Estate,sizeof(float),gridsize*gridsize,statetemp);
fwrite(h_nstate,sizeof(float),gridsize*gridsize,statetemp);
fclose(statetemp);
}*/

if (myco == 1){

getvstate <<<gridsize,gridsize>>>(d_states, d_Vstates, d_Simsize);
cudaMemcpy(h_Vstates,d_Vstates,gridsize*gridsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

fwrite(h_Vstates,sizeof(float),gridsize*gridsize,States);
myco =0;
}

myco++;
printf("%d \n",m);
}


    t2=clock();
    float diff  = ((float)t2-(float)t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f seconds \n",diff);

        delete[] h_states;
        fclose(States);
}
```

Comment: This is *way* to much code. Please short it to the main problem.

Comment: Comparing two GeForce cards is not a proof, that your code is correct. Those cards still may have some defective memory cells or similar. You should test this on a Quadro or a Tesla card.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I was using version 1.0 of cuda, and switching to any version 2.0 or higher fixes the problem.  I really have no idea why this is though.

Comment: Please post your fix as an answer.

Comment: I assume by "version of CUDA" you are actually referring to compute capability. Since your code uses double-precision data, it needs to be built for compute capability 1.3 or higher. GTX690 has compute capability 2.0, so compiling with -arch=sm_20 is an appropriate approach.

Comment: GTX690 is actually cc3.0.  However compiling for cc2.0 will fix the issue, as njuffa points out, cc1.3 or higher should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster was apparently compiling for the default CUDA architecture (1.0), which amongst other things, does not support double precision. Apparently compiling for the correct CUDA architecture (2.0) fixed the issue.

*This community wiki answer has been added from comments to remove the question from the unanswered question queue.*